# How can I compute this sum?

Tags: summation

I want to calculate the summation 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\log_2 n - 1}\frac{1}{\log_2 n-i}$$
when $n$ is a power of $2$.

Even a reasonable estimate on lower bound and upper bound on this summation is fine for me.

I know that we can establish the lower bound and upper bound using integration but I am not able to correctly establish what this bound will be.

Comment: What do you mean by this sum? $\log n$ is not an integer.

Comment: Assuming that log n is an integer, how can we compute this summation. I am solving a recurrence relation where I am not able evaluate this summation to determine the time coplexity

Comment: $\log n$ is never an integer. Do you mean $\lfloor \log n \rfloor$, the greatest integer less than or equal to $n$?

Comment: he may mean $\log_2$ or $\log_{10}$

Comment: @oldrinb is right. I am sorry I should have made this clear. The logarithm base is 2.

Answer (score 3):

Note for integer $m$ we have $$\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac1{m-k}=\sum_{j=1}^m\frac1j=H_m\sim\ln m+\gamma,$$
where $H_m$ denotes the $m$th [Harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) and $\gamma$ the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Comment: I renamed the variable to $m$ because it's not the same as the OP's $n$.

Comment: +1 good idea, I debated changing it but I was too lazy @dfeuer